# CSS : centering absolute positioned text inside relative parent

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

How can I center absolute positioned text inside fluid relative parent? I'm trying to use `text-align:center` on parent elements but it always centers child's left corner, not element itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/sucTG/2/

Comment: Why do you need the `position:absolute;` in your .text class CSS ? I just tried removing that line and the text is correctly centered;

Comment: because there will be relative elements in the blocks and I want text not to affect their positioning and just display on top of them.

Comment: To put something on top of the others, you just need positioning, not absolute necessarily.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The thing is that `position:absolute;` modifies the element's width to fit its content, and that `text-align: center;` centers the text within the element block's width. So if you add a `position: absolute;` don't forget to increase the width of the element, or else the `text-align: center;` property will be useless.

The best way to solve this is to add a `width: 100%;` and a `left: 0px;` in the .text section.

http://jsfiddle.net/27van/

Comment: I'm no css guy, but the explanation was so fine, I really enjoyed the answer and it helped me fix my issue as well.

Answer (score 16):

You can now achieve what you want more elegantly with flex.  See for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Your text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative; 
  width: 400px; /** optional **/
  height: 400px; /** optional **/
  background-color: red; /** optional **/
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /** Y-axis align **/
  justify-content: center; /** X-axis align **/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: What I put before was bad/wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/brJky/1/

This should be MUCH closer to what you want?

Your text is relative and your other elements inside the container are absolute!

```
.text {
    color:#fff;
    padding:50px 0;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.absolute {
    background:#f0f;
    height:25px; width:25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:36px; left:50%;
}
```