# Center align absolute text in a table

Tags: html, css, graph, absolute, text-align

I am making a graph, and i need to center align absolute texts depending parent, anyone have an idea ? Thanks !

Edit : I shouldn't change html code ..

[CSS : centering absolute positioned text inside relative parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147642/css-centering-absolute-positioned-text-inside-relative-parent) > Not working on table layout

[image]

```css
.graph
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 15px;
   font-family: arial;
}

.graph > div
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   text-align: center;
}

.graph > div > div
{
   animation: graph 0.5s ease-in-out;
   background: #e74c3c;
}

.graph > div > span
{
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: black;
}

@keyframes graph
{
   0%
   {
      height: 0%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
   <div><div style="height:75%;"></div><span>Valeur 1</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:100%;"></div><span>Valeur 2</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:25%;"></div><span>Valeur 3</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:85%;"></div><span>Valeur 4</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:43%;"></div><span>Valeur 5</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:65%;"></div><span>Valeur 6</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:30%;"></div><span>Valeur 7</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `position:relative;` to the parent (`.graph > div`) so the span position it self according to it

and use `left:50;` and `transform:translateX(-50%)`; on the span (`.graph > div > span`) to center it in the middle

```css
.graph
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 15px;
   font-family: arial;

}

.graph > div
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   text-align: center;
      position:relative;
}

.graph > div > div
{
   animation: graph 0.5s ease-in-out;
   background: #e74c3c;
}

.graph > div > span
{
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: black;
       left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@keyframes graph
{
   0%
   {
      height: 0%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
   <div><div style="height:75%;"></div><span>Valeur 1</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:100%;"></div><span>Valeur 2</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:25%;"></div><span>Valeur 3</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:85%;"></div><span>Valeur 4</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:43%;"></div><span>Valeur 5</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:65%;"></div><span>Valeur 6</span></div>
   <div><div style="height:30%;"></div><span>Valeur 7</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change .graph css class 
There is no need to set `position` to `obselete` or you can change it to `center`

```
.graph > div > span
{

   font-size: 12px;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply ! But in the context, these labels must be absolute ! Anyway Chiller found solution :)